# How to add/reflect query changes to the existing data in spark

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-athena

I have a table created in production with incorrect data.My rec_srt_dt and rec_end_dt columns have been loaded wrongly. rec_srt_dt is sys_dt and now I have modified the query to load the data properly. My question is how do I have to handle the existing data present in production table and how to add new changes to that data?

My source table is oracle, Using Spark for the transformations and the target table is in AWS.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: what has s3 got to do with it?

Comment: We store the source target files in s3 after applying the transformations in spark. @thebluephantom